# Can't open my site on my laptop anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I had my server and angular frontend deployed on an aws ec2 instance and everything was working fine. There was an issue with the account so I had to do everything all over again on another account. I was banging my head on the wall for a while thinking that I made a mistake somewhere lol but then I found out that I could open up the website fine on my phone using my phone data!! but I can't see the website using the home internet. I did connect to my phone's internet by using hotspot, and then I could see the website on my laptop.
I'm not sure what the issue is. I did try ipconfig /flushdns but it didn't help.

What I see on the screen is:

```
This site can’t be reached
example.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

but on my phone data I can see the website completely fine lol

Comment: Most likely the old IP address is cached on your Windows. Try using `ipconfig /flushdns` in command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all devices in your laptop's routing chain.  Since you can reach the site from your mobile device, and again on your laptop when connecting through your mobile device, it sounds like you have an issue on your home network.  Check all of your network connections.  If you have good link lights up to your router/modem, then check on the device admin pages to see if the devices are able to connect up or down.  If you can reach other sites, just not the intended one, then there might be a router issue, so try a factory reset.  If it's still having issues, check with your ISP.